# How to report a bug in a more private manner?

Tags: support, bug-reports

I found a bug, which has yet to be confirmed. The thing is that I'd rather not report it here in public view. The reason is that people can read it, and it may be exploited.

Is there an email address where I can send the reproduction steps?

Comment: http://stackexchange.com/about/contact

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Go to https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/other and fill out the form; you can find that location by clicking on the `contact us` link in the footer.

Comment: I did this; they declined ([the reply](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/89?m=7984746#7984746))

Comment: @Stormblessed: I guess that they felt it wasn't a bug that required privacy to that extent.

Comment: @Stormblessed: the method I suggest here is for *security bugs*, I'll re-confirm if this is still the best method for those.